# 2-norm and Frobenius norm of product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove $\Arrowvert AB \Arrowvert_F \leq \Arrowvert A \Arrowvert _2 \Arrowvert B\Arrowvert_F $ and $\Arrowvert AB \Arrowvert_F \leq \Arrowvert A \Arrowvert _F \Arrowvert B\Arrowvert_2$, where $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: What is the difference between the Frobenius-norm and the 2-norm on the space of $n \times n$ matrices?

Answer (score 3):

Let $ B = (b_1, ..., b_n) $, where the $b_i$'s are the columns of $B$. Then 
$$ ||AB||_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n ||Ab_i||_2^2 \leq ||A||_2^2 \sum_{i=1}^n ||b_i||_2^2 = ||A||_2^2 ||B||_F^2. $$ Taking square roots yields the desired result for the first part.
With the help of this, the other part of your question should be pretty easy to solve. (Use row partitioning for $A$ instead. The rest will be very similar.)